# Microsoft Paint color replacement not working

Tags: microsoft-paint

When I use Microsoft Paint, the color replacement tool using the eraser only works some of the time. Most of the time it does nothing.

How can I fix this?

Comment: reopen this please, as an old paint user I undrestand perfectly the question and can answer it

Comment: are you using win7 (in general, something nt 6.+)?

Answer (score 1):

The eraser uses whatever color you have set as Color 2

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem and you are correct that it will only replace pixels colored in that session; however, the Ctrl+A, Ctrl+C, and Ctrl+V maneuver has no effect when you paste it over itself.

That maneuver will work if, instead of pasting over itself, you paste into a new picture file.  MAKE sure the new doc is at least as big as the old one or you will lose some of your picture.

Also, Ctrl+A, Ctrl+X, and Ctrl+V does work.

I have the older version of Paint - the same one that came on my 2002 Gateway Desktop - and it does not have this problem.  Not sure why MS couldn't fix this flaw.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is now broken.
It only seems to replace areas that have previously been filled (using the paint tin. Otherwise it does nothing.
Another Microsoft SNAFU.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and it looks like it only works on pixels changed in the current session. I have been able to ctrl-A, crtl-C, and ctrl-V to trick it into thinking they are new. Once I paste the image over itself, I can replace with the eraser again.